# Samba file/folder deletion error after Debian 12 upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, samba, delete

I recently installed Debian 12 for Raspberry Pi and configured a Samba server. But now when I delete a file or a folder over the network I get an error, `Samba object not found` and then the file or folder gets deleted. Also if a folder contains multiple files, I have to delete all files one by one to delete that folder. This is only happening over the network. If I delete the same folder or file using a shell on the Raspberry Pi the files get deleted without any error.

This was not happening on my previous Debian 11 installation.

I have installed `cifs-utils`, `smbclient` also.

File permissions are all set to `0777` and (user and group) are for user `server`.

```
sudo chown -R server:server /media/Server
sudo chmod 0777 -R /media/Server
```

Below is the mounting string from `/etc/fstab` on the server

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxx /media/Server ntfs defaults,auto,users,uid=998,gid=992,rw,nofail 0 0
```

Below is the `smb.conf`:

```
[Server]
 path = /media/Server
 browseable = no
 read only = no
 valid users = server
 writeable = yes
 create mask=0777
 directory mask=0777
```

Kindly help me to fix the issue

Comment: Surpringly perhaps, running Samba to share a filesystem of type NTFS is not very efficient. Your Linux system has to translate NTFS into a native filesystem, and then Samba has to emulate NTFS characteristics on top of that. Can you reformat `/mnt/Server` to use a native filesystem?

Comment: Yes samba is running, I am able create a folder or file over the network without any issues. Only while deleting I am getting that error and then the file gets deleted. In debian 11 this error was not coming. It's a 4tb hdd can't format because I don't have any other media to take backup

Comment: Yes it's running on pi

Comment: Is that error message the exact text, or did you paraphrase it? Please ensure you provide the exact, complete, and full error message

Comment: Please provide the rest of the smb.conf file, not just the share definition

Comment: [2023/09/26 15:31:29.257522,  0] ../../source3/smbd/close.c:1485(close_directory)
  Could not close dir! fname=Untitled Folder, fd=29, err=2=No such file or directory  this is the log file results. I first created a folder "untitled folder" over network and then deleted it over the network.